# Invalid include path on Mac Eclipse CDT with command line tools 6.0

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

If you create a C++ Hello World Sample it will start with the warnings and alleged errors

First of all the indexer cant find iostream and hence not cout. 
The warnings are:

```
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/include).    
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1).
```

Both directories do not exist.
For

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/include
```

is correct

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include`

For

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1
```

is correct

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
```

To fix add this directories to the includes. Still this should not happen. Is this a CDT bug or does this come with the new command line tools?